# How to get good quality normalized signed random floats using System.Random?

Tags: c#, .net, random

The default Random.NextDouble returns values between 0.0 and 1.0 and I need values between -1.0 and 1.0. What's the best way to do this that will yield as good values as System.Random.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(Random.NextDouble() * 2.0) - 1.0
```